# How can I remove the small space above my sticky header in CSS?

Tags: css, header, sticky

i have been trying to remove a small space behind my sticky header but it just doesn't act the way i expect it to be.

when i scroll top and down i see that there is a small like 10px just above the header element. but i want it to be very firm at the top even before i start to scroll. it should not shift an inch when scrolling happens on the page.
the css i wrote is below: and that is the only css code in the fill

```
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  *, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
  }

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    background-color: azure;
}

.header {
    position:sticky;
    height: 10rem;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
section {
    height: 900px;
    width: 40%;
}
main {
    height: 900px;
    width: 40%;
}
aside {
    height: 900px;
    width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: Could you use a browser devtools (F12 for chrome/firefox) to see the cause? Do you see anything suspicious in here?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see your HTML file, but from what I understand you are wanting the header to always be at the top of your screen, is that so? Bear in mind that if you are using "position: sticky", the element will only get sticked to the top of your screen as you scroll, but it will start positioned wherever you've placed it.

So if you have anything above your header element, that will be occupying the space above the header until the top of the screen reaches the element when you scroll.

Perhaps you are needing "position: fixed"?

Comment: This is a guess. Do not guess at what the poster wants. They are required to provide a [mcve] so you don't have to waste your time. Do not answer such questions. answer]  Vote to close the question instead.